# How to run the Xtext .mydsl file?

Tags: java, eclipse, dsl, xtext

The question may seem obvious, but I'm just beginning with `Xtext`.
So after creating the xtext project, and running the `mydsl.xtext` file.
it launches a new iteration of eclipse. I create a new  .mydsl file in a new project.  But I don't know what to do next! How do I run the `.mydsl` file??
How do i use my `DSL`??
All Xtext tutorial stops after creating the `DSL` and don't show how to use it.
I was following [the 15 minutes Xtext tutorial](https://eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/102_domainmodelwalkthrough.html)
My code is the hello word code given by eclipse, nothing really special at this point.

Comment: When the new eclipse instance opens, create a new project and inside that create a new file with your DSL file extension. If you did everything correctly, this file will be opened with the Xtext editor of your DSL and editing should work like specified in your grammar.

Answer (score 1):

if you want a java main to read the model and execute the generator you may have a look at this snippet

```
package org.eclipse.xtext.example.domainmodel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.GeneratorContext;
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.GeneratorDelegate;
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.IGeneratorContext;
import org.eclipse.xtext.generator.JavaIoFileSystemAccess;
import org.eclipse.xtext.util.CancelIndicator;
import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.CheckMode;
import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.IResourceValidator;
import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.Issue;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.inject.Injector;

/**
 * @author dietrich - Initial contribution and API
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO traverse directory
        List<String> files = Lists.newArrayList("model/a.dmodel", "model/b.dmodel");
        Injector injector = new DomainmodelStandaloneSetup().createInjectorAndDoEMFRegistration();
        ResourceSet rs = injector.getInstance(ResourceSet.class);
        ArrayList<Resource> resources = Lists.newArrayList();
        for (String file : files) {
            Resource r = rs.getResource(URI.createFileURI(file), true);
            resources.add(r);
        }

        IResourceValidator validator = injector.getInstance(IResourceValidator.class);
        for (Resource r : resources) {
            List<Issue> issues = validator.validate(r, CheckMode.ALL, CancelIndicator.NullImpl);
            for (Issue i : issues) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }

        GeneratorDelegate generator = injector.getInstance(GeneratorDelegate.class);
        JavaIoFileSystemAccess fsa = injector.getInstance(JavaIoFileSystemAccess.class);
        fsa.setOutputPath("src-gen-code/");
        GeneratorContext context = new GeneratorContext();
        context.setCancelIndicator(CancelIndicator.NullImpl);

        for (Resource r : resources) {
            generator.generate(r, fsa, context);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In my opinion, @BR.Hamza is asking for how he can execute the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

When you save your .*yourdsl* file on the editor you temporarily opened, it will automatically build it. Once it builds successfully without errors, you will have a directory called **src-gen** inside your project, on your workspace. There you'll have the files your dsl just generated based on your *yourdsl*Generator.xtend

Answer (score 0):

The result of an Xtext project is a Domain Specific Language designed by your own, that can be parsed, validated, linked and used for code generation inside an IDE (Eclipse or Intellij as far as I know) and headless.

Depending on the features you wish to have in your DSL, you have to alter and create different classes inside your XText project.

Usually the first steps include:

- Create your grammar (`.xtext` file), to specify how your DSL should be parsed and look syntactically.
- Run the language generation for the grammar (right click on the `.xtext`  file -> run as --> generate Xtext artifacts)
- Run another eclipse instance (run as --> Eclipse Application) to see your grammar in action. For that, create a new project and put a file with your DSL File ending inside the project. A dialog will ask you to add your DSLs Project nature to the project. Agree and try to edit the file. this file should behave as specified in your xtext grammar.

Comment: I may have expressed myself wrongly, so sorry for that. i'm asking about the next step. 
I have created the project and the file with my DSL file ending and it behaves as expected. but haw i run the last file. the one that uses my DSL.I thought that expect can give me a way to execute my projects maven or gradle.